# How to make Jest expect() failure immediately exit the test suite and display results?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a promise-based Jest test with a structure like this:

```
      .then(() => {
        <some expect()s> // (A)
        return ...;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        <some expect()s> // (B)
        return ...;
      })
      .then((data) => {
        <some expect()s> // (C)
        done();          // Tell Jest the test is done.
      });
```

The problem: If one of the `expect()` checks fails in (A) or (B) or (C) then Jest waits until the test timeout before reporting the results.

How do I make Jest finish immediately and display the results as soon as an `expect()` fails?